# How to vectorize rmultinom?

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

Many `R` functions for simulating from probability distributions are vectorised. `?rmultinom` says that `dmultinom` is not vectorized, hence I assume that also `rmultinom` is not. What is the most efficient way to execute `rmultinom` repeatedly across a set of probabilities?

For example:

```
p = matrix( c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.1), ncol=4, nrow = 3, T)
```

`p` is a `3 x 4` matrix of probabilities that sum to one for each row. It is now the goal to create `n` samples of `size` for each row. For simplicity use `n=1`, `size=1`, the categorical distribution.

`rmultinom(1,1,p)` gives a `12 x 1` matrix. The desired result is a `4 x 3` matrix though, for which there is exactly 1 element equal to 1 for each column.

A `for` loop is possible but seems inefficient. Is there a better way to achieve this (for large matrices `p`)?

Comment: Have you tried `apply`? `apply(p,1,function(x) rmultinom(a,n = 1,x))`. Remember that the first value will be the sum of the resulting value for each row. So, if you write 1, you will get a 1 and the rest of values 0.

Comment: @R18 I think this works, `a=1` is indeed what is required here.

Comment: So @tomka, you will get a row with all zeros but one.

Comment: have you heard of `Vectorize`?